# How to connect RDF and database?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, jena

I'm using Jena to create rdf file. And now i don't know how to put that in database (the other way I can use is SPARQL to get dates)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Jena, you can just use [ARQ](http://incubator.apache.org/jena/documentation/query/) to execute the queries against your Jena model.

Comment: OK, but there isn't info about how put rdf file(or rather information include in it) in for example in Oracle database and then try search this info in database

Comment: Oracle is probably overkill for a prototype, however, you can use SDB to connect a Jena model to a relational database.  I suggest using a regular in-memory Jena model & ARQ to query it.  If you're new to semantic technologies, and Jena in particular, don't make it harder on yourself.  You can load and query RDF via Jena's stand-alone core APIs.

Comment: ... I still have no idea. I've got rdf file foe example `<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:vcard="http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#" > 
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://somewhere/JohnSmith">
    <vcard:FN>John Smith</vcard:FN>
    </rdf:Description>
    </rdf:RDF>
`. 
I downlaod sdb and add to java project arq.jar. I also have on localhost Oracle database. And now :
1. How put that date on database

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a [triple store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplestore) (that is, an RDF database), then load your RDF file into it. If you want to load bunches of triples progressively to your triple store, you can also use SPARQL UPDATE, if your triple store supports it (which most do now).